# javascript performance boost using pointer?

Tags: javascript, variables, pointers, object, hash

Let's say I have a javascript object.

```
var hash = { a : [ ] };
```

Now I want to edit the array `hash.a` 2 ways: first by accessing `hash.a` every time, second by making a pointer `var arr = hash.a` to store hash.a's memory address. Is second way faster, or they are the same.

Example:

```
// first way
hash.a.push(1);
hash.a.push(2);
hash.a.push(3);
hash.a.push(4);
hash.a.push(5);

//second way
var arr = hash.a;
arr.push(1);
arr.push(2);
arr.push(3);
arr.push(4);
arr.push(5);
```

Thanks a lot!

Comment: They are about the same, although you can avoid the overheadaltogether by saving hash.a directly on hash as `hash[0]` `hash[1]` etc, this is faster because it allocates one less object. Note that that sort of optimization is only required in very specific scenarios.

Comment: If I may ask, what are you actually doing?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there would be any **real** performance gain, and if there is a slight gain it isn't worth it as you are hampering legibility and maintainability of code + use more memory (creation and garbage collection of another variable **arr**, also more chances for memory leaks too if you don't handle it properly). I wouldn't recommend it.

In a typical software project, only 20% of the time is development, rest 80% is testing and maintaining it.

Comment: While this is general "good advice", it's not really backed by any evidence (the performance part).

Comment: Fine, here is quantitative performance data, with working sample :-) 
I don't see even 1 sec difference, doing it 10000000 times!
http://jsfiddle.net/p2AEx/

Comment: Oh boy :) Please consider reading [this article series](http://ericlippert.com/2013/05/14/benchmarking-mistakes-part-one/) and then perhaps [this](http://mrale.ph/blog/2013/08/14/hidden-classes-vs-jsperf.html) , if that's too hard, for the very least [this](http://ejohn.org/blog/accuracy-of-javascript-time/) explains some of the problems.

Comment: Feel free to increase the loop iterations as you wish. "If you had a simple test that ran in under 15ms the error rate would be a whopping 50-750%! You would need to have tests running for, at least, 750ms before you could safely reduce the error overhead of the browser to 1%."

Comment: I'm getting -850ms time for the second loop. Again, think about dead code elimination, the JIT, etc.

Comment: Right, so leave such optimization to the browser and write better code that is easy to read and maintain, than overdoing it :-)

Answer (score 0):

You're doing the compiler's job in this situation - any modern compiler will optimize this code when interpreting it so both cases should be the same in terms of performance.

Even if these two cases weren't optimized by the compiler, the performance gains would be negligible. Focus on making your code as readable as possible, and let compiler handle these referencing optimizations.

Comment: While this is general "good advice", it's not really backed by any evidence (the performance part).